# Guzzle 6 download file

Tags: php, guzzle, guzzle6

Need help using Guzzle 6 for downloading a file from a rest API. I don't want the file to be saved locally but downloaded from web browser. Code so far below, but believe I am missing something?

```
    <?php

//code for Guzzle etc removed

$responsesfile = $client->request('GET', 'documents/1234/content', 
        [
        'headers' => [
            'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache', 
            'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Type' => 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test"'
        ]
        ]


    );
    return $responsesfile;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Just do research inside Guzzle's docs, for example [here](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#sink)

Pass a string to specify the path to a file that will store the contents of the response body:

```php
$client->request('GET', '/stream/20', ['sink' => '/path/to/file']);
```

Pass a resource returned from fopen() to write the response to a PHP stream:

```php
$resource = fopen('/path/to/file', 'w');
$client->request('GET', '/stream/20', ['sink' => $resource]);
```

Pass a Psr\Http\Message\StreamInterface object to stream the response body to an open PSR-7 stream.

```php
$resource = fopen('/path/to/file', 'w');
$stream = GuzzleHttp\Psr7\stream_for($resource);
$client->request('GET', '/stream/20', ['save_to' => $stream]);
```

Comment: Good answer, helped med also find the stream solution. Thanks!

Comment: Good answer, I would just point out that if you do not store response to a local variable, it goes out of scope and resource is closed before you can work with it.

Comment: Is it really needed to save the response on disk? Can't I just return the response to the client directly without saving it?

Answer (score 6):

`stream_for` is deprecated in version 7.2. You can use
`GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Utils::streamFor($resource)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `Content-Type` header only makes sense when you send something (POST/PUT), but not for GET requests.

Secondly, what is your issue? Guzzle by default does not store the response body (file) somewhere, so you can work with it inside your app, like `$responsesfile->getBody()`.

Answer (score 0):

If the response from the source API, returning the actual file, contains proper headers, you can return the file for download without saving it anywhere.

Just reuse the headers from the response and return the response body. Browser will recognise that the returned response is meant for file download.

This can depend on actual php framework and how does it treat the http responses but in general you can do something like this in vanilla PHP (please note that `$downloadResponse` has been returned from GuzzleHttp `get()` method):

```
//** @var Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface $downloadResponse    
foreach ($downloadResponse->getHeaders() as $headerName => $headerValues) {
    header("$headerName:" . implode(',', $headerValues));
}
echo $downloadResponse->getBody();
```

Also note that in the example above I am not taking care of the special cases where simple imploding of the header values can cause problems (e.g. Set-Cookie values).

For the sake of better understanding I am also adding example of properly set headers from the file source API, which in combination with the presented code will result in the actual file download:

```
Date: Mon, 11 Sep 2023 15:22:41 GMT
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Length: 6850
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
access-control-allow-origin: *
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sample.pdf"
ETag: W/"1ac2-W5cdxxx7R45QxxxnBvKO+R7asd-abc"
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
```